# Accessibility bus error when packaging

Tags: quickly, python-2.7

When i do quickly package i get the flowing warning. Not a big deal but because this warning i can't share my package to my ppa.

```
** (setup.py:5679): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not 
receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply,
the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the 
network connection was broken.
```

Is there any way this fix this problem?

NOTE: I have renamed my project.